# Why is the concept of immutability is embraced in React and its ecosystem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

in ES6, there are additional ways to declare a variable such as *let* and *const*

> A variable declared with *const* cannot be re-assigned or re-declared.

Why are there so many *const* declarations in React application and what are the distinctive benefits from using *const* over *var* and *let*?

Comment: Immutability protects you against some bugs as well as increasing performance of your React components.

Comment: One of the keys to developing a good React app is *one way data flow*.  `const` is one piece of the larger puzzle of achieving this goal.  That being said, the reasons that `const` are used, and the overall goal of one way data flow is really an **opinionated** stance within the framework;  These concepts are much better researched and discussed in the framework documentation and with the project maintainers than here.

Comment: check this presentation from React team https://youtu.be/I7IdS-PbEgI which explains usage of immutables with and in React

Comment: This question could use some clarification. `const` means you can't reassign, but it is not related to immutability of the object that a variable references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty common to have multiple parts of code relying on the same variable (PI for example) . If that variable is a constant, and immutable, you dont need to worry about it changing at unpredictable times based on who may potentially be writing to it.

If a variable shouldn't change, it should be made a constant to ensure that it it isn't reassigned accidentally. That way you can trust that the value of the variable will always be the same.

Note, `const` has very little to do with immutability. Even if you have a constant reference to an object, the object itself can still change.

Answer (score 3):

First [answer by @Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44915752/1218980) explains the usage of const correctly.
But `const` keyword alone is not sufficient to achieve immutability.
e.g. You can mutate a const array :

```
const a = [12,14,15];
a[0] = 13; // allowed. but mutate a value.
```

To achieve immutability to object at property level, new JS provide using `Object.freeze()`, `.assign()` etc or you can also utilize new library like immutableJS (there are few more good one to check out).

About Immutability in React, React components are pure functions. They accept props and return view.
Pure functions are foundation of Functional Programming. They lead to all sort of benefits (enable composition, simple to comprehend the unit of code which is function, easy to test and many more). Pure function does not have any side effect. It must not modify argument object also, and treat it as immutable.

[image]

DOM created by React components forms virtual DOM, and detects the data change called via setState only. On call of `setState`, it reacts and trigger its real DOM update algorithm. If a developer updates props, this won't happen. This post explain this: http://teropa.info/blog/2015/03/02/change-and-its-detection-in-javascript-frameworks.html

React encourages one way data flow, Updated State flow down from top to bottom as props, and reaction to user action flow up as method call. One way data flow make it easy to debug/understand the react apps.

I created following diagram to understand the example illustrated in [official React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html)

[image]